# Eating and Food tags

Tags: discussion, tags, specific-tag

Can someone explain the difference between [eating](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eating) and [food](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/food)? To me it looks like they are the same...

Answer (score 1):

In an ideal world [eating](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eating) would be reserved for questions related to the event if eating, irrespective of the substance being ingested. These could include the *halachos* of eating before davening or on a fast day e.g. [food](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/food) on the other hand could be used for questions about specific foods without focus on the act of eating them. This could include questions about *kashrus*, the *minhag* of key *chala*, or hydroponic chickens - things that inhere in the food or its surroundings.

Comment: But isn't it somewhat redundant if questions are tagged with both?

Comment: If that's the intent of `food`, perhaps it should be called `foodstuffs` or `foods`.